# WAMP Server localhost - www folder doesn't run code file

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

Well, WAMP server displayed "It works!" in the localhost. But where do I actually find this? They say if we open localhost we'll see this: from the tutorial right [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html)

[image]

Also how do we run files from C:\wamp\www folder? Every time I click from file:///C:/wamp/www/ it downloads the file. What's wrong with this?

Comment: To be able to see your pages you have to use a browser with localhost in your address bar. In example: http://localhost/file.php

Comment: Now you are running, its best not to put your own code into the `\wamp\www` folder. Create a subfolder eg `wamp\www\project1` then use the address `http://localhost/project1/code.php`

Answer (score 2):

http://localhost/

This is where you found your directories and files inside the www folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the files from http://localhost (this is youre www) or 127.0.0.1 (in youre browser, like you would go to a website)

You opened it now directly from your PC. The wamp server doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

open your browser Firefox or IE or chrome and type http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1